# How does the two different syntax of union declaration give me different size?

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof, unions

I am declaring a union data type inside a struct (but two different syntax). I get different output for the size of the structs. What's the catch here?

```
union u {
    double x;
    int y;
};

union {
    double x;
    int y;
} u_1;

struct s1 {
    int a;
    union {
        int b;
        double c;
    };
};  

struct s2 {
    int a;
    union u{
        int b;
        double c;
    };
};

int main()
{
    u u1;
    s1 s_1;
    s2 s_2;

    cout<< sizeof(u1)<< " "<<sizeof(u_1)<<" " <<sizeof(s_1)<<" " <<sizeof(s_2);
}
```

I expected the output: 8 8 16 16 but the actual output is 8 8 16 4.

Comment: btw its not different ways of initialization but different ways of declaring them

Comment: Since you have no initializations in your code, I've edited your question, changing "initialization" to "declaration"

Comment: @KeithThompson Noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it comes down to alignment requirements. For x86, the alignment requirements for primitive types are to align the type on its size, i.e. a 4-byte type will be aligned on 4 bytes, an 8-byte type on 8 bytes, etc.

On x86, a class/union is aligned on the largest of its primitive members, i.e. if there is an 8-byte member, the class/union will be aligned on 8 bytes.

**In case of `s1`** we have an [anonymous union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#Anonymous_unions), which is injected into the outer scope (i.e. it becomes part of `s1`)

```
struct s1 {
    int a;
    union {
        int b;
        double c;
    };
};
```

The union's largest type is `double`, 8 bytes so the union is aligned on 8 bytes. The compiler adds 4 bytes of padding after `a` to get the union to align on 8 bytes.

We can confirm it with this:

```
cout << offsetof(s1, a) << " " << offsetof(s1, b) << " " << offsetof(s1, c) << endl;
```

Prints

```
0 8 8
```

**In case of `s2`**

`union u { ... };` is a *declaration*. It defines no element of type `u`. So `s2` has only one member, `int a;` and is 4 bytes long.

To change it into a definition, give it a name: `union u { ... } u;`

Comment: @KaushalAgarwal  I dont understand why this is accepted answer, I answered first and more comprehensively, only thing added here is **incorrect statement**
`A class/union is aligned on the largest of its primitive members` as this behaviour is implementation-defined

Comment: @user1316208 - the context of that statement is x86. Yes, it's implementation-defined.

Comment: its incorrect even on x86, its implementation defined on the compiler level

Comment: What ABI? c++ has no ABI.

Comment: The C++ [standard-layout](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class#9) types are [binary-compatible with C](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.types#footnote-42).

Comment: and C has no ABI either,  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489012/does-c-have-a-standard-abi  
So your argument is irrelevant.

Comment: It is perfectly legal c++ for compiler to setup the structure padding as it wishes, and in fact many compilers allow that to be set by user. Just google #pragma pack().

Answer (score 7):

`s2` declares a union but makes no member of it.
`s1` is using "anonymous union" semantics: (from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)

> Members of an anonymous union are injected in the enclosing scope (and
>   must not conflict with other names declared there).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have one more doubt. If an anonymous union is injected, shouldn't the struct use its maximum size? Shouldn't be it 12.

Comment: @KaushalAgarwal I see what you mean, from your output its obvious your int is size 4, it seems the compiler adds a bit of padding. ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486854/size-of-structure-with-a-char-a-double-an-int-and-a-t )  
However i dont see why this is neccessary in this case, perhaps someone more experienced can answer that.

Comment: as in the linked question the bottom line seems to be that the "data padding is implementation dependent" loosely translated as "compiler can do whatever the hell it wants".

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
struct s2 {
int a;
union u {
    int b;
    double c;
    };
};
```

to

```
struct s2 {
int a;
union u {
    int b;
    double c;
    } x;
};
```

and you'll get the same size.

Your version declares an inner type but does not create an instance of `union u`.

Your `s1` uses an anonymous union which effectively does inject an instance of your union into `s1` but without naming it.